# Is this an accurate strategy for deleting files from C:\Windows\temp safely?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, temporary-files

I read today that if you want to delete files not deleted by disk cleanup on Windows 7 in `C:\Windows\temp` that you should first restart your computer, and then after logging back in delete only files that don't have a modified date stamp of the last 24 hours.

Does doing this make sense?

Comment: Any file in that directory can be safety deleted at any point.  Any files that were in use wouldn't be deleted.  Where did you read this?

Comment: @Ramhound I read it here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/deleting-files-in-c-windows-temp.3959730/  It makes sense to me that you need to restart though, if a program is accessing one of those directories, or ya might need to find the program that's accessing the files and close it.

Comment: There are tools that will just delete everything in that folder for you that isn't in use.  Windows itself does not use this directory.  So anything deleted wouldn't effect your ability to boot your system.

Comment: If a program is using that directory then it should know better than to rely on the contents in there over *any* period of time.  If they need to guarantee the contents of a file then they can lock it which will prevent deletion, anything else is free game and any program that doesn't ensure the validity of any data in there is getting exactly what it deserves.  Disk Cleanup will just try to delete whatever it can and ignore the rest.  Any program should assume that disk cleanup can and will happen at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs should not rely on files in the temp directory for extended lengths of time.  However the whole point of that directory is that it is a place to put things for a short period of time - and it is ok to rely on it in that short term.

Generally speaking, when it comes to the temp directory, most programmers I know think of the max short term as until the next restart of the system. (In fact, I've seen certain systems automatically delete the contents of the temp directory on restart.)

Also, some bad program might keep a file open/locked by accident which will make it hard to delete until you do a restart.

For both of these reasons, it's safest to restart your system and then delete everything in temp that hasn't been touched since the restart - 24hrs is unnecessary. The reason for the time limit is that some other program or system process might have started doing things in the temp directory since you restarted.

That's what's safest.  In reality, I just delete everything in my temp directory on occasion without restarting and haven't had any problems.

Comment: Probable reasoning for the 24hours, Program installation. There still exists programs that break out into temps to do instalation, and are not finished with installation until after a reboot.  I think it is more rare now, and more compex installs are avoiding the temps. Because half installed programs are a bigger pain in the butt than some files in the temps, and automated deletion of temps, tossing in the 24 hour  thing provides a safety factor for the advice.